# Android Not building due to permission error in manifest

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth, expo

Kind Stack-overflowers, I am attempting to create an expo react native module in order to use Bluetooth, However I am experiencing a strange issue

Here is the error:

```
Missing permissions required by intent BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE: android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
```

The error occurs around this code:

```
val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
AppActivity?.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, this.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
```

This error prevents my module from building, However Strangely, When I add this property to my manifest's The one in the module with filepath: `moduleName/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml` when I add the necessary permission: as such:

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
</manifest>
```

I recieve a different, Breaking error:
`Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix`, How do I fix this? is this a known error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uses-permission tag should look like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

you were missing "android:" (namespace) before "name"

also to make sure no more errors occur add the following to you opening manifest tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

The Final manifest file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**BLUETOOTH_CONNECT** is not the right permission to request for enabling Bluetooth. The correct permission for Bluetooth is **BLUETOOTH**.

```js
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Make sure to include the xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" declaration at the beginning of the manifest tag.

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
</manifest>
```

This may solve your issue, let me know.